# Remotely kill a specific process (related to a program) on multiple hosts

Tags: windows

In order to solve a complex issue related to locking in the database engines, certain processes must be closed across multiple hosts on my windows domain.

Now that I have satisfied your curiosity as to why I would want to do this can you suggest:

1. A GUI program that can handle viewing and killing tasks across multiple computers in one shot.
2. A way to use a range of IP's in the `taskkill` command in `cmd`.
3. A suggestion on how to handle a script that might include my entire network using `taskkill` command but can run efficiently without needing to discover which IP's are actually possessed. (This is more of a last resort, as I've done research and don't see 1. or 2.)

Now imagine not having to ask 254 users to close a program!

Please be detailed and I'll clarify anything just let me know.

Comment: Sounds exactly like what `PowerShell` is for.  Have you tried writing a script?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the OS' involved but if you are running Windows 7+ on the client side then you can use PowerShell remoting to complete this...as long as you have PowerShell remoting enabled: easiest way is via GPO.

The next step is easiest when run from Server 2012R2+
Get a list of computers in either a text file and assign to a variable or in a variable using Get-ADComputer, then run a ping to find which ones are online.
Like this

$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Computers,DC=LAB,DC=COM"

$Ping = foreach ( $Computer in $Computers )
{
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $Computer | Select ComputerName, PingSucceded
}

$ReachableComputers = $Ping | Where { $_.PingSucceeded -eq $True }

Then kill the process on the reachable computers
foreach ( $ReachableComputer in $ReachableComputers )
{
Invoke-Command -Computer $ReachableComputer { Stop-Process -Name YOUR_PROCESS }
}

I've not tested this as I'm not currently at a Windows computer so let me know if you get any error messages!

Answer (score 0):

stumbled on this topic, could I suggest this [GUI app](https://www.velessoftware.com/remote-administration-tool/). it is designed exactly for managing tasks, services, scripts, processes on multiple computers.

As a side note, I am affiliated with the company that makes this software, however, I am posting this to help answer the original question and maybe for other guys that looking for same question.